# Get data from an outsider domain web-site asynchronously to prevent hanging

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ousider web-site url, that I should use in my code:

```
<img src="http://somesite.com/getpicture.php?u=user>
```

When an outsider web-site hangs-on, I get my own web-site stucked.

I wish to send a request asynchronously. I tried it with jQuery-all-kinds and haven't succeed. 
Besides, through a firebug I saw, that outsider web-site makes a redirection with 302 status.

Any tips and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The " missing in the src is only a fail here or is in your code too?

Comment: will your page need to consume the image or are you just using it for display purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help in the situation of 302 status, but try setting the size of picture, so browser can render the page (other elements) even without actual picture.

```
<img src="http://somesite.com/getpicture.php?u=user" width="32" height="32">
```